# Show/Hide specified number of table row

Tags: jquery, html, css, jscript

This is the HTML table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="border-bottom:1px solid #EB8D01;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;font-family: verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom: 2px;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/">Auto</a> <span class="count">(1)</span> </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/17-Cars/">Cars</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/18-Car-Accessories/">Car Accessories</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/20-Car-Cleaning-Detailing/">Car Cleaning &amp; Detailing</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/24-Car-Audio/">Car Audio</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/29-Motorcycles/">Motorcycles</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/35-Other-Commercial-Vehicles/">Other Commercial Vehicles</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/39-Driving-Schools/">Driving Schools</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/41-Service-repairs/">Service &amp; repairs</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/42-Spare-parts/">Spare parts</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/43-Transport-Services/">Transport Services</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/393-Boats-Jet-Skis/">Boats &amp; Jet Skis</a><br></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6d191oj7/)

I would like to show a specified number of table rows (for example 5) with a Show/Hide link at the bottom.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tried this: $("table tr:gt(5)").hide();
But it didn't work.

Comment: There is a reason it gives a warning that links to JS fiddle needs to be accompanied with code. Please don't ignore it or go around it. Post all the code in your question and also what you have tried.

Comment: @user3216677 your code works in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6d191oj7/2/).

Comment: @user3216677 Can you check my answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.nth-child()` as shown :-

```
$("table tr:nth-child(5)").hide(); //in '.nth-child()' count starts from 1
```

OR

```
$("table").find('tr').eq(4).hide();  // in '.eq()' count starts from 0
```

Above shown answers will hide only specified row i.e only `'5th'` row,if need to hide all the rows after `5th` row try below answer.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6d191oj7/1/)

[Demo with show hide option.](http://jsfiddle.net/6d191oj7/3/)

---

```
$("table tr:gt(5)").hide();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6d191oj7/4/)

Comment: @user3216677..the fiddle you include have no jquery file included that is why problem occurs .. see demo in answer.

Comment: Thanks Kartikeya, But what about the Show/Hide link at the bottom?

Comment: There is a problem, Show/Hide link is not working properly. Its not hiding all the rows below 5.

Comment: Worked this time, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, change your HTML like this:

```
<a href="#">Show / Hide All</a>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="border-bottom:1px solid #EB8D01;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;font-family: verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom: 2px;">
                <a href="0/posts/10-Auto/">Auto</a> <span class="count">(1)</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/17-Cars/">Cars</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/18-Car-Accessories/">Car Accessories</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/20-Car-Cleaning-Detailing/">Car Cleaning &amp; Detailing</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/24-Car-Audio/">Car Audio</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/29-Motorcycles/">Motorcycles</a><br></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="more hidden">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/35-Other-Commercial-Vehicles/">Other Commercial Vehicles</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/39-Driving-Schools/">Driving Schools</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/41-Service-repairs/">Service &amp; repairs</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/42-Spare-parts/">Spare parts</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/43-Transport-Services/">Transport Services</a><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 2px;border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;"><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/393-Boats-Jet-Skis/">Boats &amp; Jet Skis</a><br></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(".more").toggleClass("hidden");
        return false;
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/rkss956e/

Comment: Unfortunately i can't make any changes to html table coz data is fetched from sql database.